# Not able to load and predict with dill:ed keras Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

I have a `keras LSTM` model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(128, implenetation=0))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
```

that I have trained and dumped into a dill file. On the same computer, at a later time, I now am trying to load this model and make predictions on some now incoming data with `predict_proba`. But I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("embedding_1_input:0", shape=(?, 53), dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397) and tried out the method. Fitting and dumping model:

```
### Creating and dumping model
model.fit(X, labels)
dill.dump(model, open(model_file, 'wb'))
```

Loading and making predictions, with the lines added from the linked thread marked `# added`:

```
model = dill.load(open(model_file, 'rb'))
model._make_prediction_function()           # added
graph = tf.get_default_graph()              # added
with graph.as_default():                    # added
    model.predict_proba(new_X)
```

But now I instead get a different error:

```
`ValueError: Tensor Tensor("activation_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 18), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I have misunderstood how to implement this "solution", or is there any other error causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "model.save(filepath)" and "model = load_model(filepath)" as described [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)?

If you really want to use dill to save / load the graph, can you provide complete code with random input?